# How to add php stylesheet to admin section instead of admin_head hook

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-style

how can we do the below code using separate file let say admin-style.php

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_style');
function custom_admin_style() {
   $bg_color = get_option('custom_color');
   echo '<style>';
   echo 'body { background: #' . $bg_color . '}';
   echo '</style>;
}
```

Comment: have you seen `admin_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: You will need to include `admin-style.php` file in `functions.php` file.

Comment: yes i know `admin_enqueue_scripts` but how can we add dynamically generated css which needs to composed after some wordpress functions as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Wyck if i need to attach `admin-style.php` using including `admin_enqueue_scripts` i need to include `wp-load.php` file to get access to wp functions right? Is there any other way to compose `admin-style.php` and include it to admin head?

Answer (score 0):

If you enqueue your style sheet first you should be able to use wp_add_inline_style afterwards.

```
function custom_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('your_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'style/your_css.css' );
    $bg_color = get_option('custom_color');
    $custom_css = " body { background-color: {$bg_color}; }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'your_css', $custom_css );
}
```

This is not tested (just written from mind) and I have never used it in the admin section. Just test it with admin_enqueue_scripts.

Comment: brilliant answer. This is somewhat am looking for. Let me try that.

Comment: Did it work? You never updated this questions.